# Php, Date Format throwing away the '0' in front of single digit date

Tags: php, date, format

When I do the below code:

```
date("d/m/y", $date)
```

It gives me

> 04/06/15

How can I make it such a way that it will return

> 4/6/15

What modifications must I do in order to get the desired output? Please advise thanks.

Comment: read the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php it's all in there.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
date("j/n/y", $date);
```

Try this one

Answer (score 0):

```
date("j/n/Y", $date)
```

That helped what I wanted.